# Error in eval_tidy (xs [[j]], mask): object 'titles' not found

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

When I try this code, I get an error. I want to scrape the data from multiple pages. But when I try the script down below, I get an error that says:

> Error in eval_tidy (xs [[j]], mask): object 'titles' not found

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# function to scrape all elements also missing elements
scrape_css <- function(css, group, html_page) {
  txt <- html_page %>%
    html_nodes(group) %>%
    lapply(
      . %>%
        html_nodes(css) %>%
        html_text() %>%
        ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)
    ) %>%
    unlist()
  return(txt)
}

# Get all elements from 1 page
get_one_page <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)

  titles <- scrape_css(
    ".recipe-card_title__1oIb-",
    ".recipe-grid-lane_recipeCardColumn__2ILMo",
    html_page
  )
  minutes <- scrape_css(
    ".recipe-card-properties_property__2tGuH:nth-child(1)",
    ".recipe-grid-lane_recipeCardColumn__2ILMo",
    html_page
  )
  callories <- scrape_css(
    ".recipe-card-properties_property__2tGuH:nth-child(2)",
    ".recipe-grid-lane_recipeCardColumn__2ILMo",
    html_page
  )
}

return(tibble(titles = titles, minutes = minutes, callories = callories))

url <- ("https://www.ah.nl/allerhande/recepten/R-L1473207825981/suikerbewust")

appie <- get_one_page(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `return` should be inside the curly braces at the end of the function

   ```
    return(tibble(titles = titles, minutes = minutes, callories = callories))
   }
   ```
2. You forgot to update the variable name such that you have

   ```
   html <- read_html(url)
   ```

   when you need

   ```
   html_page <- read_html(url)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This does *not* per se answer @Laila's question, but I ran into the

> Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : object '' not found

error, when I did sth similar to

```
tibble(
  a = 1,
  b = ,
  c = NA
)
```

So basically, forgot to enter a value for a tibble column. But it is a rather uninformative error message. I am leaving this for the future me (and others) as a reference, as there are not many posts related to this error.